# Alemaña/Almanya/ألمانيا etymology

Tags: historical-linguistics, arabic, spanish, turkish

Turkish, Arabic, Spanish for "Germany" are obviously cognate.  But not with "Germany" or Deutschland.

At least two of them must be borrowed.  Which, and what is the (commonly assumed) source?

Comment: A good adress to get a first hint is [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Allemagne#Etymology). BTW, same for French (*Allemagne*), Spanish (*Alemania*), ...

Comment: Says the French got it from Latin.  Doesn't say where Spanish, Turkish, Arabic, or Latin got it from (though probably Spanish got it from Latin).  BTW, Spanish is _Alemaña_.

Comment: It does, just check the sites in the corresponding languages (e.g. [Latin](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Alemannia#Latin)). Also possibly relevant to you: The "Descendants" section, providing the "reverse etymology" (i.e. a list of all words that this word is a common origin of). About Spanish: Sorry, you are of course right, that was some kind of Freudian slip trying to spell it phonetically.

Comment: There is discussion of the Germanic etymology at http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=Alemanni.

Comment: Good suggestions.  Probably at least one of them worthy of promotion to "answer."  I expected Wiktionary to show them all on one page, forgetting that it only happens when they're all spelled the same.

Comment: As an interesting side note, people with less schooling (mostly from rural areas) tend to say "Alamanya" (Germany) instead of "Almanya". AFAIK, the former pronunciation is closer to the French and Spanish versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spanish *Alemaña* (as well as French *Allemagne* and Portuguese *Alemanha*) derives from Latin *Alemannia*, which in turn comes from *Alemanni*, which was a confederation of German tribes. The [Online Etymological dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=Alemanni) says this comes from Proto-Germanic *Alamanniz*, which possibly meant "all men" (which makes sence, since they were a confederation); an alternative would be "other men", from Latin *alius* and Proto-Germanic *manniz*.

It could also be that the Spanish word is a borrowing from French, as it was among the Franks that *Allemand* first became a term for all "Germans". In this case the etymology of the Spanish word would be more complicated: Proto-Germanic -> Latin -> Frankish -> Old French -> Spanish.

The Arabic word must have been borrowed from Spanish, and the Turkish word would then be a borrowing from Arabic.

---

To take into account the comments below, Spanish *Alemaña* derives from Latin *Alemannia*, either through Frankish -> Old French -> Spanish or through Frankish -> Iberian Romance -> Spanish. The Arabic word must be a borrowing from Iberian Romance or Spanish (because a literate borrowing from Latin would result in word similar to *Germania*, which was the Classic Latin most common name for the region and its people), and the Turkish word must be a borrowing from Arabic (because if they acquired the word via Eastern Europe instead, they would most likely borrow from either German *Deustcheland*, Greek Γερμανία, or some slavic language, in which case it would ressemble something like *Njemačka*).

Comment: Why must the Arabic source have been Spanish rather than Latin?

Comment: @user6726 - Because Spain was under Moorish rule for half a millenium. But since Spanish was still forming during that period, it would probably be safer to say that the Arabic word was borrowed from Iberic Romance.

Comment: I understand the history of Spain, but I assume you know that they had contact with Latin, so on cultural grounds both sources are plausible. How do you decide that it could not have been from Latin?

Comment: @user6726: probably because the Arabs were not interested in Latin.  the actual people they had contact with did not speak latin.

Comment: I see, so you're assuming the Arabs didn't have a reading knowledge of Latin or Greek, and didn't read works written in the classical languages?

Comment: @user6726 I suppose that if they borrowed the word directly from Latin, especially if from classic sources, they wold borrow *Germania*, instead of *Alemannia*.